# does sudo always set process limits to the numbers from /etc/security/limits.d?

Tags: shell, sudo, limit

I have observed the following behavior:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-66-68-55 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-66-68-55 3.4.103-76.114.amzn1.x86_64 #1
SMP Fri Sep 12 00:57:39 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[ec2-user@ip-10-66-68-55 ~]$ ulimit -H -n; ulimit -S -n
1000
1000
[ec2-user@ip-10-66-68-55 ~]$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/80-nofile.conf
ec2-user hard nofile 123456
ec2-user soft nofile 123456
[ec2-user@ip-10-66-68-55 ~]$ bash -c 'ulimit -H -n; ulimit -S -n'
#I expect this limit to be 1000,  same as above. it is.
1000
1000
[ec2-user@ip-10-66-68-55 ~]$ sudo -u ec2-user bash -c 'ulimit -H -n; ulimit -S -n'
#I expected this limit to be 1000,  the same as if I had not called sudo -u ec2-user
#Instead, I get the one from limits.d/80-nofile.conf. 
123456 
123456
```

A quick search through the sudo man page did not show any direct reference to /etc/security/limits.

I want to rely on this behavior for ensuring that a daemon I care about runs with the limits set on 80-nofile.conf, but I don't know reliable this is. Is it documented somewhere?

What kinds of config files / variables affect this behavior? can I tell sudo to not override the current limits?

Comment: You should probably look in /etc/pam.d/sudo and check if pam_limits.so is required in it or in files it is including...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably take a look inside `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file and check if `pam_limits.so` is required in it or in any of the other files it includes.

For example, the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file in my system looks like below.

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Now, you can look for `pam_limits.so` in the other files that are included using the **@inlude** parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @hrv for the insight. I've confirmed after a quick experiment: when the /etc/pam.d/sudo included pam_limits.so, then running sudo did set them, and when the /etc/pam.d/sudo did not include them, then running sudo didn't set them.

I checked a couple of different machines and one of them did include pam_limits.so within /etc/pam.d/sudo while the other one did not.